# How to get position of each element in a collection using handlebar

Tags: handlebars.js

If I have something like :

```
{
 people: [
          "Yehuda Katz",
          "Alan Johnson",
          "Charles Jolley"
         ]
}
```

How do I get the position of each of the values in handlebar?

```
{{#each people}}
   {{this}}
   <!--{{this.position}} -->

{{/each}}
```

I expect the answer to be

```
           Yehuda Katz
           0
           Alan Johnson
           1
           Charles Jolley
           2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own block expression, like 'each_with_index', to accomplish this. You can find out how to create this custom expression in the Handlebars documentation here: http://handlebarsjs.com/#block-expressions

Here's a quick and dirty way to do it:

```
var people = [ 'Yehuda Katz', 'Alan Johnson', 'Charles Jolley' ];

var source = '{{#each_with_index people}}' +
             '{{ this.index }}: {{ this.item }}\n' +
             '{{/each_with_index}}';

Handlebars.registerHelper('each_with_index', function(items, options) {
  var output = '';
  var item_count = items.length;
  var item;

  for (var index = 0; index < item_count; index ++) {
    item = items[index];

      output = output + options.fn({ item: item, index: index });
  }

  return output;
});

var $output = $('#output');
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var result = template({ people: people });

$output.html(result);
```

To see it working: http://jsfiddle.net/EECFR/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use `@index`:

```
{{#each people}}
  {{this}}
  {{@index}}
{{/each}}
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EECFR/20/) (modified from Carl's)

From http://handlebarsjs.com/#iteration:

> When looping through items in each, you can optionally reference the current loop index via `{{@index}}`

```
{{#each array}}
  {{@index}}: {{this}}
{{/each}}
```